# MySQL Create entry for each row in a table

Tags: mysql

I know there must be an answer to this, but I can't seem to put the search terms together properly.

Say I have an existing table 'foo'

```
foo
| id | data1 | data2 | ... |
----------------------------
|1   | abc   | def   | ghi |
|2   | abc   | def   | ghi |
...
```

And I want to create a new table, bar that has a 1 to 1 relationship with foo where foo gets a new foreign key column called barId, and each entry of foo MUST have a related barID so the end result looks like:

```
foo
| id | data1 | data2 | ... | barID |
------------------------------------
|1   | abc   | def   | ghi | 1     |
|2   | abc   | def   | ghi | 2     |
...

bar
| id | dataA | dataB |
----------------------
| 1. | null  | null  |
| 2. | null  | null  |
```

The trouble I'm having is that after I define bar I am having trouble creating a row for each entry of foo, and subsequently setting foo.barId for each newly created bar record.

If I were to do this in a procedural language, I would write something like the pseudocode below

```
createTable(bar);
foo.createColumn("barId"); 
for each (entry in foo) {
    barEntry = bar.createNewEntry();
    entry.setBarId(barEntry.ID);
}
```

How can I accomplish this goal with MySQL?

Comment: what trouble are you having? any errors?  can you add details around how you are trying to create a row?

Comment: I don't understand any of this. How is a table of nulls useful? Perhaps if the example was less abstract?

Comment: I just don't know how to go about it. How would i create an entry in bar for each existing entry of foo?

And I used null because the actual data in the table does not matter. What matters to me is that a link between foo and bar exists and there is an entry in bar for each entry of foo.

Answer (score 1):

What part(s) of the problem does the following fail to address?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;

CREATE TABLE users
(user_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,user_name VARCHAR(12) UNIQUE
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_role;

CREATE TABLE user_role
(user_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,role ENUM('guest','user','administrator')
);

INSERT INTO users VALUES (NULL,'John');

INSERT INTO user_role VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'administrator');

 SELECT * FROM users;
+---------+-----------+
| user_id | user_name |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 | John      |
+---------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM user_role;
+---------+---------------+
| user_id | role          |
+---------+---------------+
|       1 | administrator |
+---------+---------------+
```

EDIT: And extending this idea, consider the following...

```
INSERT INTO users (user_name) VALUES ('Paul'),('George'),('Ringo');

INSERT IGNORE INTO user_role SELECT user_id, 'guest' FROM users;

SELECT * FROM users;
+---------+-----------+
| user_id | user_name |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 | John      |
|       2 | Paul      |
|       3 | George    |
|       4 | Ringo     |
+---------+-----------+

SELECT * FROM user_role;
+---------+---------------+
| user_id | role          |
+---------+---------------+
|       1 | administrator |
|       2 | guest         |
|       3 | guest         |
|       4 | guest         |
+---------+---------------+
```

Note that it's slightly unusual to store 1-1 relations in separate tables, but there can be valid reasons for doing so - particularly relating to permissions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, and this comes down to me not asking the question properly- in my question, the 'users' table is roughly the 'foo' table and the 'user_role' would roughly be bar.

So the key portion that I think this does not address is that in my example, users already exists and has many entries. 

What I need to solve is how to create entries in a new user_role table such that each user entry has a unique entry in user_roles and the user table has a foreign key to user_role that is filled out with an id from the newly created entries in user_role.

Comment: I edited the initial comment with some pseudo code to try to illustrate specifically what I am trying to achieve with MySQL